# How do I make text show up on top of Markers using Carto in TileMill

Tags: labeling, symbology, tilemill

I'm attempting to place intersection markers on a trail map. Each intersection has a number. I can't seem to get the text show up above the marker. If I use the opacity, I can see the text is underneath. Is there an option I'm missing?

Here's the output:
[image]

And here's the Carto:

```
#intersections {
  text-name: "[Name]";
  text-placement: point;
  text-fill: black;
  text-face-name: @labels;
  text-size: 12;
  marker-width:10;
  marker-fill:#fff;
  marker-line-color:#333;
  marker-allow-overlap: true;
  marker-placement: point;
  marker-opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike normal CSS, the order of your properties matters in Carto - reverse the marker and text rules and it'll reverse their order in rendering.

You must also make sure to set `text-allow-overlap` to `true`.

Comment: This worked once I set `text-allow-overlap` to `true` as well. I updated your answer to reflect this. It's awaiting review.